# Django permissions and content_type objects after model deletion

Tags: python, django, django-models

When a Django model is deleted, its permissions and content_type objects related to it keep on existing, do they have any other purpose too? or should they have been deleted with the model?

Comment: You can delete it. There is also data in django_content_type about model, it is used not only for permissions but aslo for admin_log